# Insert Latex to Inkscape in Windows

Tags: latex, inkscape

I have Windows 7 64 bit. I installed these with the given order:

1. Miktex (Basic-miktex-2.9.4521.exe)
2. Ghost script (gs905w32.exe)
3. GSView (gsv50w32.exe)
4. Pstoedit (pstoeditsetup_win32.exe)
5. Inkscape (Inkscape-0.48.2-1-win32.exe)

However, I still am not able to see `Extensions -> Render -> Latex Formula` in `Inkscape`. What is missing?

Comment: Okay, after adding `miktext`, `gs` and `pstoedit` to the `PATH`; it worked fine.

Comment: Since you solved your problem, please consider answering your own question, and accept that answer. In the future, people with a similar issue will be able to quickly find your solution then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, after adding `miktext`, `gs` and `pstoedit` to the `PATH`; it worked fine.

For example, in order to add `pstoedit` to the path:

```
Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > PATH > Edit
```

Add the following:

```
;C:\Program Files (x86)\pstoedit;
```

PS: Don't forget semi colons.

Good luck.

Comment: You can use Rapid Environment Editor for editing variables. Do you mean miktex?

Comment: I had to add `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.16\bin` and `C:\Program Files\pstoedit` to the `PATH` variable. MikTex (`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\`) was already in the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Just a note: make sure you get the 32 bit version of pstoedit, the 64 bit version can create errors

Answer (score 5):

This helped me, but I still got errors. I solved them after a while though, so this is what you have to look out for:

When you add the programs to the path, don't use spaces after a semicolon!!

When you type your code later in Incscape, it requires the dollar signs to indicate a formula, even though it asks for LaTeX Formula, so it seems you should already be in math mode. Example: $\vec{r_p}$. You still get lots of warnings, but at least it produces what you want.

Just adding this in case others may have the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that the latest ghostscript version (at the time of writing) 9.22 throws some depriciation errors but using the version suggested in the accepted answer (by Sait), 9.05, fixed everything for me. Thanks!

I used the following versions on Windows 10:

1. Miktex (MiKTeX2.9, 32 bit I think; this one may be Basic-miktex-2.9.4521.exe)
2. Ghost script (gs905w32.exe and NOT the latest at the time, gs922w32.exe)
3. GSView (gsv50w32.exe)
4. Pstoedit (pstoeditsetup_win32.exe)
5. ImageMagick (ImageMagick- 7.0.7-Q16)
6. Inkscape (Inkscape 0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06), presumably 32 bit)

Caveats:

1. I used 32 bit versions, the 64 bit did not work at first some other problem)
2. Ghost Script version 9.22 was throwing some depreciation errors. Version 9.05 worked like a charm.
3. While installing pstoedit I checked: ".h and .lib files for using the pstoedit.dll in other programs" and "plugins SVG, MIF, EMF, CGM format (shareware)"
4. I had image magick installed.

Source: http://knowledgepayback.blogspot.be/2017/09/surface-pro-2017-optimising-for.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the existing answer unsatisfactory. MikTeX already ships with tools to convert PDF to SVG, and to compile LaTeX to PDF, so the dependencies seem rather artificial. I have found that one can build a newer version of the LaTeX extension which uses these tools https://github.com/juanjosegarciaripoll/inkscape-latex-miktex

Just copy the *.inx and *.py files into the Inkscape/share/extensions folder and start Inkscape. The interface is very primitive, and equations cannot be edited, but it works.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which specifically asks how to get a particular built-in feature of Inkscape to function.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to make latex work with Inkscape is explained in [this site ...](http://yeknan.free.fr/dc2/index.php?post/2015/02/12/Textext)
The only things that should be checked are the paths added to environment variables if more recent versions are used.

Here is a quote of the proposed procedure (sorry, it is in Frensh):

> Choisissez les fichiers d’installation 32 ou 64 bits en fonction de votre système. Si vous ne savez pas lequel il vous faut : Clic droit sur l’icône Ordinateur (sur le Bureau ou dans le Menu Windows) → Propriétés, l’information est affichée dans Système : Type du système.
>
> - Installer Miktex, Ghostscript, Ghostview, ImageMagick
> - Installer pstoedit en personnalisant l’installation :
>
>   - Installation dans le dossier de Gostgum : C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\pstoedit
>   - Cocher : « .h and .lib files for using the pstoedit.dll in other programs » et « plugins SVG, MIF, EMF, CGM format (shareware) »
> - Copier les fichiers textext.py et textext.inx dans : C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions
> - Extraire site-packages.zip dans : C:\Program Files\Inkscape\python\Lib\site-packages
> - Clic droit Ordinateur (sur le Bureau ou dans le Menu Windows) : Propriétés → Paramètres système avancés → Variables d'environnement… Dans Variables système → Path, ajouter :
>     ;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\lib;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin;C:\Program Files\ghostgum\pstoedit